# Track Changes in navigation property

Tags: entity-framework-4

```
 public partial class ClaimEntities : DbContext
        {
            public ClaimEntities()
                : base("name=ClaimEntities")
            {
                this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public DbSet<ClaimInformation> ClaimInformations { get; set; }
            public DbSet<ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode> ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode { get; set; }
           }

    }


    public partial class ClaimInformation 
    {
     public List<ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode> OtherDiagnosisCodes
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode.Where(c => c.CodeQualifier == "BF" || c.CodeQualifier == "ABF").ToList();
                }

            }
    }


    public partial class ClaimInformation
        {
            public ClaimInformation()
            {
             this.ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode = new ObservableListSource<ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode>();
            }
public virtual ObservableListSource<ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode> ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode { get; set; }
        }
```

ClaimInformation_HealthcareCodes is a navigation property on the entity ClaimInformation. 1-M between ClaimInformation and ClaimInformation_healthcareCodes. One Claim can have many ClaimHealthcareCodes. 
This is how it is loaded in the context

```
 _context.ClaimInformations.Include(h => h.ClaimInformation_HealthCareCode)
```

How do I make the context detect a change in the navigation property. In the code I am deleting a healthcareCode entry. This is a list in the ClaimInformationClass and is virtual. 1-M 
this.claiminformation.claiminfo_healthcarecodes[i].remove(); This line is connected to the context.

```
     private string GetTableName(DbEntityEntry dbEntry)
            {
                string entryName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name;
                int length = entryName.IndexOf('_');
                TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), 
false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;
                string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : entryName.Substring(0,length);
                return tableName;
            }
```

This code returns the changed entry as 'ClaimInformation' which is partly true but it has to go a little deeper to to the navigation property which has a deleted entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private string GetTableName(DbEntityEntry ent)
        {
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext;
            System.Type entityType = ent.Entity.GetType();

```
        if (entityType.BaseType != null && entityType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
            entityType = entityType.BaseType;

        string entityTypeName = entityType.Name;

        EntityContainer container =
            objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
        string entitySetName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                                where meta.ElementType.Name == entityTypeName
                                select meta.Name).First();
        return entitySetName;
    }
```

Changed it to get the entity name instead of table name